# Is there a better way to do a server-client application?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client

I'm making an application server client using tcp sockets in c# ..

The application has multi tasks like file transfer .. file manager .. chat .. (voice chat later)

So I decided to create a socket to receive the commands as a string
and another socket to transfer files .. 
is that a good way for programming a server-client application or should I try another way?
because user could send a message while receiving/sending a file

and how could I tell the (file-transfer-server) accept only the same client who has already connected with the main server

ex: server listen on port 8000 and accept clients .. and file transfer on port 8111

```
public StartSever()
{
    sr = new StreamReader(networkStream);
while(connected)
{
        string[] command = sr.ReadLine().split(',');
        switch (Command[0])
        {
            case "RecFile":
                StartFileTransferServer();  // creating new socket tcp listens on port 8111
                Receiving();
                break;
            case "SendFile":
                StartFileTransferServer();  // creating new socket tcp listens on port 8111
                Sending();
                break;
            case "Chat":
                chat(Command[1]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

}
```

Comment: Look into the Command pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some kind of communication framework or library which would abstract the details of TCP/IP sockets and allow you to send objects and messages and files between your client and server end and not have to worry about all the details.

Some things you could look into using instead:

- [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324)
- [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)
- [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Those are just some examples I thought of off of the top of my head there are tons of such frameworks that work at different levels of abstraction and offer more heavy or light weight implementations. I'm sure you could find one that meets your basic needs.

Comment: i checked all of those links and i watched 2 tutorials .. but actually i dont feel that it helps me because i have no idea about WCF it sounds complicated to me .. is there any other ways can help?

Answer (score 1):

> The application has multi tasks like file transfer .. file manager .. chat .. (voice chat later)

If you haven't gotten longer than using a colon separated string protocol and `switch` statements I recommend that you stop right there.

I strongly suggest that you use WCF with netTcpBinding and duplex binding instead: http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,b891610a-6b78-4b54-b9a6-4ec81c82b7c0.aspx

You will not succeed with a VoiceChat on your own. Buy a component for that.

Comment: the code im using is pretty complicated and i dont want to make it hard for others to understand my question so i post this simple code which makes my question easier
your answer is no where near my question.. i asked about creating new socket connection for file transfer
.. btw i've already done a small voice chat application

Comment: still. I've coded multi-threaded socket servers for the past 10 years. I'm surprised that you managed to code your own voice application (which is not an easy task) but can't figure out to do a simple file transfer. imho my answer still apply. I'm not trying to be a smart ass but to save you from a lot of unnecessary pain.

Comment: my file transfer is working fine .. im just looking for a better steps or ideas to do it .. im still a 3rd year student im just improving my self and finding the shortest way to do it .. i've checked WCF links but i still dont know why should i use it.. n i've no idea about it .. thanks anyway

Comment: Using a separate socket is the way to go. Do note that you need to check the file on completion so that the transfer wasn't exited because of failure. I suggest that you study the FTP protocol and get some ideas from it.

Comment: should i use it instead of TCP protocol for sending files ?

Comment: i searched about FTP .. all i see that FTP about uploading/downloading.. and sites "@ftp://1.1.1.1/MAIN/Dir1"...
it doesn't look like its going to help me in file tansfer between two computers project !

Comment: If you have studied more you would have seen that FTP uses one socket for commands and one for the file transfer. You would also have seen that it supports resume transfer etc. And if you had googled a C# implementation you would have gotten ideas how to do those things.

Answer (score 0):

When you call Accept you receive socket for new user. After this you can create NetworkStream.
Write and Read are blocking methods. You can try to use asynchronous methods: BeginRead and BeginWrite.
Also creating new thread per user is not good if you will have thousands users.
I propose such solution: One thread Accpects connections and send work to threads pool.

Something like this (note this is only draft):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleServer
{
class Program
{
    private static void Worker(Object sockObj)
    {
        var mySocket = (Socket) sockObj;
        using(var netStream = new NetworkStream(mySocket))
        {
            //Handle work;
        }            
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int port = 80;
        // create the socket
        Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                         SocketType.Stream,
                                         ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // bind the listening socket to the port
        IPAddress hostIP = (Dns.Resolve(IPAddress.Any.ToString())).AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(hostIP, port);
        listenSocket.Bind(ep);

        // start listening
        listenSocket.Listen(125);

        while (true)
        {
            Socket mySocket = listenSocket.Accept();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Worker), mySocket);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: as u see im using a networkstream.. it works fine..
im just checking if there another way like.. creating another networkstream for the same socket.. and let one for commands and chat and the other one for file transfer ..  ur idea sounds better about "One thread Accpects connections and send work to threads pool." .. do u have any tutorial or some simple example so i can understand it ?